# Unable to click an element after scrolling on both simulator/real device

Tags: java, ios, selenium, appium, appium-ios

after scrolling i try to find and click an element but java fails to do that with the "no such element exception" error, this is weird because i know my xpath is correct and the element is there, if i try to click it before swiping, the element is found, but only after swiping and then swiping back where the element is, i always get that exception, i am making sure the element is visible on the phone screen.

I think i have tried all combinations like, driver.getpagesource(), lock and unlock device, runappinthebackground, but its impossible to click the element.

```
  //the element is here but i have to do some other operations before and those operations take me to the end of the screen, thats why i have to swipe back with following code to get back to where my element is located.




int startX = licenceLabel.getLocation().getX() + (licenceLabel.getSize().getWidth() / 2);
            int startY = licenceLabel.getLocation().getY() + (licenceLabel.getSize().getHeight() / 2);

            int endX = paintLabel.getLocation().getX() + (paintLabel.getSize().getWidth() / 2);
            int endY = paintLabel.getLocation().getY() + (paintLabel.getSize().getHeight() / 2);

            TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver);
            action.longPress(PointOption.point(startX, startY))
                    .moveTo(PointOption.point(endX, endY))
                    .release()
                    .perform();

            System.out.println("swipe complete");

            Thread.sleep(3000);
            MobileElement el1 =  driver.findElementByXPath("//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name='Federal Motor Vehicle Standards Compliance Label']/XCUIElementTypeButton[1]");
            el1.click();

    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
    For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
    System info: host: 'spro', ip: 'fe8...', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.5', java.version: '1.8.0_162'
    Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
    Capabilities {app: ..., autoAcceptAlerts: true, autoWebview: false, automationName: XCuiTest, browserName: , databaseEnabled: false, deviceName: iPhone 8, fullReset: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: false, networkConnectionEnabled: false, noReset: true, platform: MAC, platformName: iOS, platformVersion: 12.2, takesScreenshot: true, udid: 6CD3..., webStorageEnabled: false}
    Session ID: 4b0b...
    *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//XCUIElementTypeOther[@name='Federal Motor Vehicle Standards Compliance Label']/XCUIElementTypeButton[1]}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
```

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the app once the swipe is done? Try adding a sleep and inspecting it during the sleep. Appium inspector should see exactly the same as your code automation, and i've seen strange behaviors where things aren't visible (bounds are way off).

Comment: Yup, for some reason, elements are not visible according to the code, so i am trying the Actions method to force clicking on a non visible element, also i learnt a technique of limiting the scope, so for example i find an element and then look for other elements inside that element, maybe its obvios but since i am a beginner i am discovering all these things little by little.